# how to filter data frame with conditions of many columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Update！！！
after trying the code in the comment.
the result shows me all brand_id which the review_score is 5 (the highest score).
While there are also more than thousands of brand_id over 10 reviews...

### thus I'm still confused about it

the thing is I get a data frame with many columns, and I need to find the brand with different conditions for different columns.

Here is the data frame:

| Brand id | Brand name | review score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1.0 |
| 2 | B | 2.0 |
| 2 | B | 3.0 |
| 3 | C | 1.0 |
| 3 | C | 1.5 |
| 3 | C | 2.0 |

And I need to What's the Brand id for this item with the highest review score? And also filter for this item with more than 10 reviews?

I tried code like this:

```
item %>%  
  group_by(Brandid, review_score) %>%
  summarise(idnumber = n()) %>%
  filter(idnumber > 10)%>%
  arrange(desc(review_scode))
```

And I tried this, also failed..

```
item %>%
  group_by(Brand_id) %>%
  mutate(n = n(), 'max' = max(review_overall, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
  filter(n >= 10) %>%
  arrange(desc('max'))
```

Then I got many items with the same review_scode...
But seems there should be only one answer to this question.

So could you please help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With this code you get the max `review_score` for each Brand.
Using `add_count` you get the count of each Brand.

There is no column `review_overall`:
Maybe you could clarify:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Brand_name) %>% 
    add_count() %>% 
    filter(review_score == max(review_score))
```

In case you want to filter `n` too, use this code:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(Brand_name) %>% 
    add_count() %>% 
    filter(review_score == max(review_score & n > 10))
```

Output:

```
  Brand_id Brand_name review_score     n
     <int> <chr>             <dbl> <int>
1        1 A                     1     1
2        2 B                     3     2
3        3 C                     2     3
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But seems this code doesn't  【filter for this item with more than 10 reviews】

Comment: Hi. What do you mean 10 reviews. sum of the score or ...

Comment: Yes. You could that was in my mind but I was not sure. Please tell me if it worked.

Comment: Hi, I think it means the number of reviews!

Comment: Hi TarJar, after considering the question. I think the number of reviews means more than 10 highest reviews. So may I ask how to filter the brand_id with more than 10 highest reviews.

Comment: Could you `dput(head(df))` and post to your question. I suspect that you need the sum of `review_score` for each `Brand_id` which in my opinion the same as  `Brand_name`. But I can't figure it out...

Comment: Try this with your dataframe `df %>% 
    group_by(Brand_name) %>% 
    add_count() %>% 
    filter(review_score == max(review_score)) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    slice_max(review_score, n = 10)`

Comment: Thank you!!! Maybe I need `sum()` .. I'll thinking about it ! thank you for your help!!!